# Restkit 0.20: Customising what is sent to the server on PUT/POST with foreign key relationships

Tags: ios, restkit, restkit-0.20

e.g. if I have the following entities

```
User = ['ident' => NSUInteger, 'username' => NSString, 'name' => NSString, 'email' => NSString]
Comment = ['ident' => NSUInteger, 'user' => User, 'message' => NSString]
```

If I then post a `Comment` to the server RESTKit will send this as follows:

```
{
    'ident': ...,
    'user': {
        'ident': ...,
        'username': ...,
        'name': ...,
        'email': ...
    },
    'message': ...
}
```

When really all I need to hook up the foreign keys server side is the following:

```
{
    'ident': ...,
    'user': {
        'ident': ...  
    },
    'message': ...
}
```

Is there anyway to configure RESTKit in such a way - e.g. the request descriptor - that it only maps a subset of the the attributes of objects within relations? As of yet I haven't been able to find such a feature but would like to avoid having to hack at RESTKit itself to perform this...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Exactly, it's the mapping you use with the request descriptor. I guess you're using `inverseMapping`? But you don't need to, you can create a new mapping with only the parts you need. You can even use key paths to navigate to the user and extract the `ident` without needing to add any nesting into the generated JSON.

Comment: Worked like a charm. Cheers.